How do I go about kmapping a boolean expression of 6 variables using splitting?
Say I want the SOP. I plan to split the kmap into kmaps of 3 variables each then get their respective SOPs. After which, do I need to combine the SOPs? If so, how? What if my SOPs from all kmaps are (AB+C) and (A+B)?

Some idea. Is it possible to express the expression's function as the sum of eight functions of 3 variables? If not, how can those SOPs help?
